# How to stop sequential release of all system calls with ping command and timeout in c++ made when an unreachable route turns up?

Tags: c++, linux, ping, system-calls, boost-filesystem

I am working on a application feature in C++ on Linux machine that requires checking the network connectivity of a NAS before writing csv files to it. For testing purpose, I am replacing the route reachability with a black hole path using:

```
ip -4 route add 172.17.15.17 via 172.17.15.101
```

When I issue the above command, the NAS path becomes unreachable, but it leaves a weird affect on the system. Any command issued on the NAS path such as **ls, mkdir, or even cd** into the NAS directory stalls the terminal session with only one way out of it, and that is to close the current terminal session and open a new one.

Firstly, I thought that using the boost filesystem's **is_directory()** function in my C++ application will throw a **filesystem_error** exception saying that the path isn't reachable, but in the end even the exceptions weren't thrown for this case. Here's the code:

```
try{
    if(boost::filesystem::is_directory(dir) == true){
        boost::filesystem::create_directory(dir);
}
catch(boost::filesystem::filesystem_error &e){
  // write to log traces with LOG_ERR 
}
```

Thinking that this is the same stalling effect as seen before, I moved on to the idea of making a system call to check reachability using ping utility with the timeout option as below:

```
if(system("ping -w2  172.17.15.17") == 0){
    //route is reachable 
    do something ........
}else{
    //route not reachable 
    return;
}
```

This worked for me,and I was almost going to settle with this as a final code change when I noticed that once I made the route to NAS reachable by issuing

```
 ip -4 route del 172.17.15.17 via 172.17.15.101
```

all the unsuccessful ping tries that were made since the route became unreachable were released all togethe one after the another.

For better understanding, lets say that after 5 ping checks which resulted into failure to find route to NAS, I made the route reachable issuing the above command. To my surprise, I saw that more than one ping request was in the log traces under /var/log/messages. It is as if the ping requests were queued somewhere in the OS buffer, and were released one after another when NAS was made reachable.

Now this may work in certain cases, but the number of ping requests that will be sent out through the system call when a route becomes reachable is certainly too much overload considering that the NAS connectivity check logic will be happening frequently.

Is there a way that I can limit the number of pings to only one per iteration through system call without this queued affect, or Is there a better way ?